# Adding a whole ipv6 /64 block to a ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, ubuntu-18.04, netplan

I know there are other questions that had already asked this, but the solutions don't work (anymore and for me).

I added the IP in the netplan config file(01-netcfg.yml):

```
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [37.xxx.xxx.4/22, "2a03:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64", "92.xxx.xxx.xxx/22"]
      gateway4: 37.xxx.xxx.1
      gateway6: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [46.xxx.xxx.230, 46.xxx.xxx.230, "2a03:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::e1e6", "2a03:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx", "1.1.1.1"]
```

This configuration does work, but it only makes this one IP (2a03:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1) available. There must be way to assign the whole IP block the the network card, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bind a (large) block of addresses to an interface?](https://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface)

Comment: no it doesnt, I now can ping the server from the outside, but for example curl can't bind the ip e.g. `curl --interface 2a03:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64 http://icanhazip.com`

Comment: I want to be able to use every ip address in the subnet in the curl command. e.g. `2a03:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1, 2a03:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2, 2a03:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::3` and so on

Comment: Then you also need [How to bind a non-local IPv6 address?](https://serverfault.com/q/236626/126632)