# Adding a whole /64 block to a network interface - again!

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6

Okay, so, there were A LOT of different answers for this thing. [Someone](https://serverfault.com/questions/1024390/adding-a-whole-ipv6-64-block-to-a-ubuntu-18-04-server) had the same problem as me.

Here's what i tried already from all these existing answers:

- disabling DAD and enabling nonlocal bind:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth0.dad_transmits=0
sysctl net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

- then i tried doing the things from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/971732/1056105):

```
ndppd 
# (warning) Low prefix length (64 <= 120) when using 'static' method
# it's running in a seperate screen btw, i didn't terminate it 

ip add add local 2a09:7c40:0:f::/64 dev lo
# ignored the route command, because i already had it configured
# ignored the sysctl, because i already had it enabled

curl --interface 2a09:7c40:0:f::2145 https://api64.ipify.org/
# the curl command didnt work, it timeouted

# had the same ip assigned to loopback and ens3, so i tried removing it from ens3:
ip addr del 2a09:7c40:0:f::/64 dev ens3

curl --interface 2a09:7c40:0:f::2145 https://api64.ipify.org/
# the curl command still didnt work, it timeouted
```

Maybe the `curl --interface` option is not working well with nonlocal binds, so I tried doing the same previous commands, but I replaced curl with [freebind](https://github.com/blechschmidt/freebind):

```
freebind -r 2a09:7c40:0:f::/64 -- wget -qO- ipv6.wtfismyip.com/text
```

And it also didn't work, just like everything before.

There's a workaround for this problem for anyone who is tired of this, you can just add an address everytime you need it, like here:

```
ip -6 address add 2a09:7c40:0:f::2145/64 dev ens3
curl --interface 2a09:7c40:0:f::2145 https://api64.ipify.org/
ip -6 address del 2a09:7c40:0:f::2145/64 dev ens3
```

But that workaround doesn't work well for big amount of IPs used at once.

So, the question is: **how do I make this thing finally work?**

### Edit: here's the output of ip -6 route

```
root@ghp:~# ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a09:7c40:0:f::/64 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2a09:7c40::1 dev ens3 metric 1024 onlink pref medium
```

with lo interface set in routing table, it fails with no route to host,
with ens3 interface set, it just timeouts

Comment: [Here](https://transfer.sh/O08jg60aaV/icmpv6-425.pcap)'s a ICMPv6 packet capture from tcpdump if that would help anyone in solving this problem

Comment: omg, so what should i follow to get an IPv6 range i got from my hosting to work?

Comment: i did the exact steps which were there, and  after typing that local route command i get a new entry in the routing table: `2a09:7c40:0:f::/64 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
`, and when trying to use curl + freebind with that it fails with no route to host.

also, it's an VPS, not a dedicated server, so this could be the problem - should i just ask the VPS provider to add that ndppd entry to their config? will that fix my problem?

Comment: Specifically you did not do this line from your own link ( https://serverfault.com/questions/590038/adding-a-whole-ipv6-64-block-to-an-network-interface-on-debian/971732#971732) : `ip route add local 2001::41d0:2:ad64::/64 dev eth0` note the keyword `local` that is not present in your routes. Instead you wrote: "ignored the route command, because i already had it configured"

Comment: `ip route add local 2a09:7c40:0:f::/64 dev ens3` fails with
`RTNETLINK answers: File exists` - tried deleting all routes but still the same error, so what could be the issue now?